# Choosing the data structure for orgaininsng data with list of values in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a map as shown below in which there is a key and values is of type `List`:

```
Map<String, List<String> newdatamap = new HashMap<>();
map.put ("RtyName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
map.put ("rtyRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"))
```

I'd like to add another map over the previous map, such that there is a key and its value will be the above map. Is this the correct data structure, and how do we implement it?

I want something like this shown below

```
Key         Value

B1          RtyName  ----> "weepn", "weepfnb", "eedgeft", "xbteehy"
            rtyRate ----->"deed", "ww", "terrty", "hteetyure"



B2          RtyName  ----> "SSSweepn", "wpefSSSnb", "GGeGdgeft", "xbteYYYYhy"
            rtyRate ----->"WWded", "wTeTYw", "YYYYtrerty", "IIIehttyure"
```

As shown above, only a new key is been introduced to the map, and its value is the previous map.

so it is like a `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>` whis becomes a complex data structure can i organise the data structure as
for example one class containing a Map, so it will be like

```
Map<B1 , RtyName>
Map<B2 ,rtyRate>
```

and  payer nae contain list of values such as

```
 RtyName  ----> "SSSweepn", "wpefSSSnb", "GGeGdgeft", "xbteYYYYhy"
  rtyRate ----->"deed", "ww", "terrty", "hteetyure"
```

so in the above structure complexity will be low since at the end for B1 i have to search key that wiil be RtyName and against payer name further i have to search values which will be  "wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"

please advise whheteher map will be best or is there any other better data structure also to obtain this .

one data structure coming in my mind is of Guava's Table

```
  final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
values.put("B1", "RtyName", Lists.newArrayList("weepn", "weepfnb", "eedgeft", "xbteehy"));
System.out.println(values.get("B1", "RtyName")); // prints the list
```

My objective is that any data structure I can have in which against B1 I will get Rtyname and for Rtyname I will get possible list of values

Comment: why don't you declare a simple POJO that holds two lists for `Rtyname` and `rtyRate` and put the objects of that class into the map instead of nesting maps and lists?

Comment: Seems reasonable. What are the concerns besides complexity? Will you ever need to access members without knowing the B1 or B2 keys? Consider using `enum` Instead of `String` when you have a limited set of known values

Comment: In order to choose a data structure, begin by writing down the requirements, especially the forms of insertion, removal, and search.

Comment: Your last example suggests you just want lists that can be referenced using **two identifiers/keys in combination**. If this is the case (is this the case?), it would be better to have a function that generates a key based on these two values (and is independent of order), in the manner of a hash function, and then simply use this function to reference a single `Map<String, List<String>` data structure.

Comment: @ROman vottner can you please show let's say a pojo named ABC is created and two list for Rtyname and rtyRAte is created then how I would manage

Comment: @chris well for B1 have to search value that is RtyName and then for RTyNAme I have to pick one value from list

Comment: @RIver Thanks for the solution but please show or post a little bit in order to grasp more please show the function will be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("B1".hashCode()+"RtyName".hashCode(), Arrays.asList("weepn", "weepfnb", "eedgeft", "xbteehy"));
dataMap.put("B1".hashCode()+"rtyRate".hashCode(), Arrays.asList("deed", "ww", "terrty", "hteetyure"));
dataMap.put("B2".hashCode()+"RtyName".hashCode(), Arrays.asList("SSSweepn", "wpefSSSnb", "GGeGdgeft", "xbteYYYYhy"));
dataMap.put("B2".hashCode()+"rtyRate".hashCode(), Arrays.asList("WWded", "wTeTYw", "YYYYtrerty", "IIIehttyure"));
```

Which would represent:

```
B1, RtyName  ----> "weepn", "weepfnb", "eedgeft", "xbteehy"
B1, rtyRate ----->"deed", "ww", "terrty", "hteetyure"

B2, RtyName  ----> "SSSweepn", "wpefSSSnb", "GGeGdgeft", "xbteYYYYhy"
B2, rtyRate ----->"WWded", "wTeTYw", "YYYYtrerty", "IIIehttyure"
```

Note that `hashCode` is just a convient function from the `String` class that meets my needs. You could roll your own that returns a `String` key (or really anything else) if you preferred.

Actually since your original method didn't require an order independent function, you could really even concatenate the `String` keys to use as a new key:

```
dataMap.put("B1"+"RtyName", Arrays.asList(/*your list here*/));
```

This is a little less convenient (and not as "good" programmatically) than the first method, but still much better than nesting `Map` classes. (And makes keys much easier to recognize when outputted than `hashCode`.)

## Two-way Mapping

#### Values as Keys

If you want each `List` value to map to keys as well as the other way around, you need a second `Map`:

```
Map<List<String>, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>(); //New map for value->key 
for(String key: dataMap.keySet()) //Get all keys
    valueMap.put(dataMap.get(key), key); //Create mapping value->key
```

#### Each Item in Value as a Key

If you want each `String` item in the `values` list to map to `keys` as well as the other way around, you need a second `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<>(); //New map for item->key mapping
    for(String key: dataMap.keySet()) //Get all keys and iterate through
        for(String item: dataMap.get(key)) //For each item in your value list
            itemMap.put(item, key); //Create new mapping item->key
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80936/discussion-on-answer-by-river-choosing-the-data-structure-for-orgaininsng-data-w).

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for it:

You simply define a class, `ABC` in this case as you've suggested that name, which holds two lists, the `RtyName` and the `rtyRate` list:

```
public class ABC {
    private List<String> RtyName;
    private List<String> rtyRate;

    public ABC(List<String> RtyName, List<String> rtyRate) {
        setRtyNames(RtyName);
        setRtyRates(rtyRate);
    }

    public void setRtyNames(List<String> RtyName) {
        this.RtyName = RtyName;
    }

    public List<String> getRtyNames() {
        return this.RtyName;
    }

    public void setRtyRates(List<String> rtyRate) {
        this.rtyRate = rtyRate;
    }

    public List<String> getRtyRates() {
        return this.rtyRate;
    }
}
```

Once this class is ready, you can change your map definition to:

```
Map<String, ABC> newdatamap = new HashMap<>();
```

And assign new values to it similar as you already did before - instead of nesting those lists in a further map and putting this map into the outer map though, you create a new instance of ABC, provide the two lists as input parameter and put the resulting ABC object into the map (formally the outer map):

```
List<String> RtyName = Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy");
List<String> rtyRate = Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure");
newdatamap.put("B1", new ABC(RtyName, rtyRate));
```

You could also assign those lists directly as input-parameters:

```
newdatamap.put("B2", new ABC(Arrays.asList("SSSweepn", "wpefSSSnb", "GGeGdgeft", "xbteYYYYhy"), 
                             Arrays.asList("WWded", "wTeTYw", "YYYYtrerty", "IIIehttyure"));
```

An entry is now simply retrieved on calling `get(String)` as you already used to do:

```
ABC data = newdatamap.get("B1);
```

You can also retrieve one of the lists directly like:

```
List<String> RtyNames = newdatamap.get("B1").getRtyNames();
```

In my opinion this is way easier to manage and to read at the same time. On top of that, you gain also runtime-saftiness as you do not run into eventual typing errors for `RtyName` or `rtyRate`.

**Update for redesign**

If `RtyName` entries and `rtyRate` entries always go hand in hand, f.e. `wpn` is the name and `dd` is the assigned rate, grouping those fields together would make sense. Therefore you could refactor your code to furthermore reduce one list and introduce a new class:

```
public class RtyEntry {
    private String name;
    private String rate;

    public RtyEntry(String name, String rate) {
        setName(name);
        setRate(rate);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getRate() {
        return this.rate;
    }
}
```

If you now change ABC to only contain one list of RtyEntry objects like this:

```
public class ABC {
    private List<RtyEntry> rtyEntries;

    public ABC(List<RtyEntry> rtyEntries) {
        this.rtyEntries = rtyEntries;
    }

    public ABC() {
        this.rtyEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setRtyEntries(List<RtyEntry> rtyEntries) {
        this.rtyEntries = rtyEntries;
    }

    public List<RtyEntry> getRtyEntries() {
        return this.rtyEntries;
    }

    // convenience methods

    public void addRtyEntry(RtyEntry entry) {
        this.rtyEntries.add(entry);
    }
}
```

The creation would now change to:

```
RtyEntry entry1 = new RtyEntry("wpn", "dd");
List<RtyEntry> entries = Arrays.asList(entry1, ...);
newdatamap.put("B1", new ABC(entries));
```

You can then also assign new entries like that:

```
newdatamap.get("B1").addRtyEntry(new RtyEntry("wpfnb", "ww"));
```

Retrieving entries also changed to the refactoring:

```
ABC data = newdatamap.get("B1");
List<RtyEntry> entries = data.getRtyEntries();
for (RtyEntry entry : entries) {
    System.out.println(entry.getName() + " has a rate of: " + entry.getRate());
}
```

Of course you can also retrieve the list directly via:

```
List<RtyEntry> entries = newdatamap.get("B1").getRtyEntries();
```

as before.