# alternative data structure to map in java for storing below daata

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to store the data structure something like this shown below in which there is a map whose values is again a nested map as shown below

```
Key               Value
                  (Key)           (Value)
B1       -->   TradeRef  ----> "tradeRef1", "tradeRef2";
               Dealdate  ----> "DealDate1", "DealDate2"; 

B2       -->   TradeRef  ----> "tradeRef33", "tradeRef44";
               Dealdate  ----> "DealDate22", "DealDate24";
```

so i have developed below code to achieve this which is working fine 
below is the piece of code shown

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mapOfMapOfStrings =   new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();

HashMap<String, List<String>> b1Map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> b2Map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();      




        ArrayList<String> B1tradeRefList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> B1dealDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> B2tradeRefList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> B2dealDateList = new ArrayList<String>();


        B1tradeRefList.add("tradeRef1");
        B1tradeRefList.add("tradeRef2");
        B1dealDateList.add("DealDate1");
        B1dealDateList.add("DealDate2");

        B2tradeRefList.add("tradeRef33");
        B2tradeRefList.add("tradeRef44");
        B2dealDateList.add("DealDate22");
        B2dealDateList.add("DealDate24");



        b1Map.put("TradeRef", B1tradeRefList);
        b1Map.put("Dealdate", B1dealDateList);

        b2Map.put("TradeRef", B2tradeRefList);
        b2Map.put("Dealdate", B2dealDateList);

        mapOfMapOfStrings.put("B1", b1Map);
        mapOfMapOfStrings.put("B2", b2Map);
```

now also please advise as i have shown above the data structure that I have chosen can this same approach be implemented by using any other data structure in an efficient manner may be by creating custom data structure or may be by using tree or linked list also as i want to explore the custom data structures implementation of the same above functionality other than map please

Comment: Why do you want another data structure? This looks like it's working fine and with good efficiency. (Although you can avoid nested `Map` structure, which would probably be a bit better in memory efficiency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814228/choosing-the-data-structure-for-orgaininsng-data-with-list-of-values-in-java/30814436#30814436)

Comment: @River how can i avoid nested map please advise Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you be able to flatten it a bit. This can be done by a helping class. The last Map could be a class with a field id and the Map<String, List<String>>, then putting all in a List<CustomClass>. But a then you have to iterate to find the the id class.

Comment: Just look at that link... It is simply done by combining your keys into a single key instead of a key to a key.

Comment: @NwDx Thanks a lot just a small request can you please code a little bit that will help to grasp more clearly a bit Thanks inadvance

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. Avoid creating the same question with new accounts.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza this is different a bit please , just go through the question please i am looking for some other custom data structure

Comment: Well, you may omit `Map<String, List<String>>` and use Guava's Multimap, that will ease lot of work when adding data. In the end, you may have `Map<String, MultiMap<String, String>>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks a lot agree with you but i am using kdk 1.5 in my project please advise Guava's Multimap will work with jdk 1.5

Comment: You can just open a new window/tab in your browser, use your favorite web search online engine (e.g. www.google.com) and do the research rather than always asking for us to give you all the info on a silver platter.